# Responsive images with srcset

Tags: images, mobile, responsive

I know I have to use wp_get_attachment_image_srcset but I don't know how and where to put it?Any help

```
<picture>
 <source media="(max-width: 659px)" srcset="inc/images/activity-large.png">
  <source media="(min-width: 660px)" srcset="inc/images/activity-small.png">
  <img src="inc/images/activity-small.png" alt="">
 </picture>
```

Comment: Well what does `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset()` return and where would that fit in your code (aka which values can be replaced)? I'm not sure if this is the method you need, as it only returns a single string with all the srcset in it. You can [check out how it works under the hood](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_srcset/#source) and replicate that to your needs

Comment: @kero using this code but I don't think it's working <?php
// Get this attachment ID
$attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
 $srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id,array( 290, 198 ) );
 $new  = wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $attachment_id, 'activities-thumb' );
?><picture>
  <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'activities-thumb') ?>"
      srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $srcset ); ?>"
      sizes="(max-width: 659px) , (min-width: 660px)" >
      </picture>

Comment: "_I don't think it's working_" isn't a proper error description. Which HTML gets produced by this code? Where is it wrong?

Comment: [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) will add the appropriate `srcset` attributes. If you want to use the `source` tag, then you'd likely need to manually input/enter the URL of the appropriate image. Or get their ID and use it with `wp_get_attachment_image_url()`..